# Does paperclip require all 4 columns (_file_name, _content_type,etc)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am wondering if Paperclip does require all four columns in database as:

```
  add_column :users, :avatar_file_name,    :string
  add_column :users, :avatar_content_type, :string
  add_column :users, :avatar_file_size,    :integer
  add_column :users, :avatar_updated_at,   :datetime
```

Can I just add the avatar_file_name? And not add the other 3 columns?

It is because I wont to use paperclip instead of the filecolumn gem. And it uses only 1 column therefor I don´t want fill out all columns that paperclip support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you could just add one column + 3 `attr_accessor` playing a dummy role.

But this looks awkward and I wouldn't advise to do so.

Comment: This is correct. All Paperclip requires is that you have `attr_accessor`s for each attribute that paperclip requires.